# Powershell, add items in order to hashtable

Tags: powershell, sorting, hashtable

I have the following sample script

```
$aDomains = @{}

$aDomains['a-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['b-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['c-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['d-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['e-test.nl'] = @{}

$aDomains
```

It seems very straight forward, but if I run this script, the output is very unexpected:

```
$aDomains


Name                           Value                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                
e-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
d-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
b-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
a-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
c-test.nl                      {}
```

How can I get the output to match the order of items being added? I do need to use the @{} on all instances due to what happens next in the script.

Also, adding this in the script has no effect at all:

```
$aDomains = $aDomains | Sort-Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default a hashtable is not ordered, as you saw. Since PowerShell 3.0, you can make a hashtable ordered, in which case it will keep the order.

See the below example:

```
$aDomains = [ordered] @{}

$aDomains['e-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['a-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['b-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['c-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['d-test.nl'] = @{}
$aDomains['e-test.nl'] = @{}

$aDomains

Name                           Value                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                
e-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
a-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
b-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
c-test.nl                      {}                                                                                   
d-test.nl                      {}
```

As you can see, the e-test.nl is in the list twice, but only added once at the top, so it does pertain the order of added, and won't add something twice. To get this to work, add the `[ordered]` tag to the beginning of the hashtable assignment.

Small sidenode though. If you use the .ContainsKey() function, this needs to be changed to .Contains()

Comment: Strictly speaking, ```[ordered]```creates a ```System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary``` as opposed to a ```System.Collections.Hashtable```, but they both implement ```System.Collections.IDictionary``` so they can be used interchangeably in most cases. Try ```([ordered] @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }).GetType()``` to see this in action...

Comment: @mclayton thanks. Yeah I found that out as I posted the question and found the answer. So far, they behave mostly the same, only ContainsKey vs Contains is different for what my script uses, but all the counting and stuff works the same.

Comment: Yw :-). Note also you can use ```Contains``` on hashtables *and* ordered dictionaries because it's a member of ```IDictionary```, whereas ```ContainsKey``` is a direct member of hashtable so it only works on that type.

Comment: @mclayton Oh, that is good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we unwrap this object into it’s individual elements,then we can sort it.

```
$aDomains= $aDomains.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorting was not really what I was after. I needed to add things in a certain order and pertain that order. Thanks for the answer though. +1